# Why is my program stopping before reading the txt file?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file, printf, fopen

My code keeps closing before reading the file, I made a comment where it closes. Does anyone know why it wont work? I showed it to my lecturer but she couldn't figure it out and then she had to leave so I was wondering if anyone here could figure it out!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RESULT_MAX = 100;
#define RESULT_MIN = 0;

int main() 
{

    int studentId;
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int result;

    FILE *fPtr;

    if ((fPtr = fopen("student.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("File could not be opened\n");
            //exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the Id, first name, last name and result\n");
        scanf("%d %s %s %d", &studentId, firstName, lastName, &result);
        while(!feof(stdin) )
        {
            fprintf(fPtr, "%d %s %s %d\n", studentId, firstName, lastName, result);
            scanf("%d %s %s %d", &studentId, firstName, lastName, &result);
        }

        fclose(fPtr);
    }//else end

// MY PROGRAM ENDS HERE AND WONT CONTINUE!


    if ((fPtr = fopen("student.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("File could not be opened\n");
            //exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Id, first name, last name, result ");
        fscanf(fPtr, "%d %s %s %d", &studentId, firstName, lastName, &result);

        while(!feof(fPtr) )
        {
            printf("%d %s %s %d \n", studentId, firstName, lastName, result);
            fscanf(fPtr, "%d %s %s %d", &studentId, firstName, lastName, &result);

        }//end while
    fclose( fPtr );
    }//end if




}
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Set breakpoints? Checked varaible's actual values against expected values? What exactly goes wrong? What do you mean by "stop" / "ending"?

Comment: How do you end your console input? Ctrl-C ?

Comment: [`while(!feof(file))`is always wrong](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) and I don't think you need `=` in those `#define`s. Also, what is your input?

Comment: Post your input.  Candidate issues: `scanf("%d %s %s ...` is unsafe as the input may exceed the space for `firstName`, `lastName`.   2) The return value of `scanf()` is not checked, so how does code know input valid occurred?

Comment: @CoolGuy, thanks for catching the '=' operators in the #defines.  That cleared up a problem I was having when testing the OPs code

Answer (score 0):

```
the problem is actually the line: 'while(!feof(stdin) )'  
because feof() only becomes valid when the program 
tries to read past the end of the 'stdin' file.   

This is something that cannot be accomplished

suggest 
modifying the program to:
1) read into a local buffer[] array, in a loop, 
2) using fgets() as the loop control
3) have a leading 'q' (or similar) as an indication of having read all input
4) output a prompt for every input line
5) if going to parse the fields, parse them using 
   strtok()/atoi() strncpy() strncpy() atoi()
   or perhaps
   sscanf()
6) check first char of input buffer[] for the end marker (the 'q' above)
   to exit the input loop before parsing

there is a similar problem with the 
loop reading the file
I.E. do not use feof() for loop control
    rather use fgets()

to differentiate each line of input written to the file, modify
the fprintf(fPtr, ... ) format string to include a trailing '\n'
```

Comment: in the future, you can (in general) forget the existence of the feof() function.  It rarely works as expected

Comment: this would be a good time to learn to use a debugger, like gdb